# How to find the Document Library URL by its Email Address

Tags: document-library, incoming-email

I have only the Email Address of the document library and have to find the exact location of the document library, is this something possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Eric said, you shouldn't be directly querying the database. I would recommend using the PowerShell to check `CanReceiveEmail` and `EmailAlias` properties of `SPList` to exactly find the list location. See the script below:

```
$SPsite = Get-SPSite "http://mysitecollection"
foreach($SPweb in $SPsite.AllWebs)  # get the collection of sub sites
{
    foreach ($SPList list in $SPweb.Lists)
    {
        if ( ($splist.CanReceiveEmail) -and ($SPlist.EmailAlias -eq "yourEmailAliasForList") )
        {
            WRITE-HOST "E-Mail: " $SPList.EmailAlias + “, List: ” + $SPlist.Title +”, Web: ” + $SPweb.Url
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT FullUrl      
  FROM [Prod].[dbo].[AllWebs]
  where
  id in (
  SELECT tp_WebId      
  FROM [Prod].[dbo].[AllLists]
  where tp_EmailAlias in ('xyz','abc')
  )
```

Comment: Querying the DB is never a good idea, try looking at the SPList class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @PirateEric, I do understand that however is there any direct way of doing it? Iterating all through the SharePoint farm is impossible.

Comment: It is not impossible, there are methods to iterate from farm to web app to site colelctions to sites to lists to get the data. You just have to walk down the tree.